# JavaMail invalid MSGID

Tags: java, email, jboss, jakarta-mail, postfix-mta

I am running a JBoss server with underlaying Postfix server. When I am sending emails, JavaMail creates a invalid messageID, e.g. Message-ID: <47112553230.139.4972667128159.JavaMail.undefined>.

I am using this code for sending mails:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "xxx.tld");
props.put("mail.host", "xxx.tld");
InitialContext ictx = new InitialContext(props);
Session sess = (Session) ictx.lookup("java:jboss/mail/Default");
Transport trans = sess.getTransport("smtp");
trans.connect();

MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(sess);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
msg.addRecipients(RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to, false));
msg.setSubject(subject);
msg.setText(message);
msg.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"");
msg.saveChanges();

Transport.send(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
trans.close();
```

The main postfix configuration:

```
myhostname = xxx.tld
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = xxx.tld, Debian-60-squeeze-64-minimal, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1
```

How can I fix this problem?

Best regards,
Christian

Comment: What makes you think the message-ID is invalid?

Comment: <47112553230.139.4972667128159.JavaMail.undefined> does not include the top-level domain. SpamAssasin flags the mail with "INVALID_MSGID".

Comment: You're right, it should at least include a "@".  The part that is "undefined" in your Message-ID comes from the [InternetAddress.getLocalAddress](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#getLocalAddress(javax.mail.Session)) method; read the javadocs for details.  As far as I can see, the only way the value can be "undefined" is if the property "mail.from" is set to "undefined".  If getLocalAddress returns null, JavaMail will use "javamailuser@localhost".

Comment: I added the line
    props.put("mail.from", "foobar@xxx.tld");
but the same problem.

Comment: I don't know anything about JBoss but the properties you're passing to the InitialContext constructor may not be flowing through to the JavaMail Session.  Perhaps there's a way to set the properties directly in the Session resource in JNDI?  Otherwise, use sess.setProperty to set the property.

Comment: @BillShannon: Thank you, you were right! The properties are not passed to the mail session. My current solution: I open a session, get the session properties (for authetification) and change/add the missing properties. Then I reopen the session with the new properties map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I could fix the problem with the help of @BillShannon:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
InitialContext ictx = new InitialContext(props);
Session sess = (Session) ictx.lookup("java:jboss/mail/Default");
props = sess.getProperties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "xxx.tld");
props.put("mail.host", "xxx.tld");
props.put("mail.from", "yyy@xxx.tld");
sess = Session.getInstance(props);
```

Comment: You don't need to get a new Session.  The property changes you make will affect the current Session.

Comment: Okay, I tested it and it works. I really appreciate your help.